# Update table from android,

Tags: php, android

I want to update a table in my database using Android. I have some checkbox and I assign a value if it's chek or not. I try to insert those values in my database using PHP. Whne I click on the button for do the update I have the follow error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query`
I don't know why it happens beause I haven't special characters.

This is the code of the activity

```
public class Disponibilidad extends Activity {
String v;
String sm;
String st;
String dm;
String dt;
String l;
String m;
String x;
String j;
String c;
String mo;
String usuario;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_disponibilidad);
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    usuario=bundle.getString("usuario");
    final CheckBox chV=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chV);
    final CheckBox chSM=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chSM);
    final CheckBox chST=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chST);
    final CheckBox chDM=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chDM);
    final CheckBox chDT=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chDT);
    final CheckBox chL=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chL);
    final CheckBox chM=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chM);
    final CheckBox chX=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chX);
    final CheckBox chJ=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chJ);
    final CheckBox chC=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chC);
    final CheckBox chMo=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chMo);
    Button btnEnviarDisponibilidad=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEnviarDisponibilidad);
    btnEnviarDisponibilidad.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v1){
            if(chV.isChecked()==true){
                v="Si";
            }
            else{
                v="No";
            }
            if(chSM.isChecked()==true){
                sm="Si";
            }
            else{
                sm="No";
            }
            if(chST.isChecked()==true){
                st="Si";
            }
            else{
                st="No";
            }
            if(chDM.isChecked()==true){
                dm="Si";
            }
            else{
                dm="No";
            }
            if(chDT.isChecked()==true){
                dt="Si";
            }
            else{
                dt="No";
            }
            if(chL.isChecked()==true){
                l="Si";
            }
            else{
                l="No";
            }
            if(chM.isChecked()==true){
                m="Si";
            }
            else{
                m="No";
            }
            if(chX.isChecked()==true){
                x="Si";
            }
            else{
                x="No";
            }
            if(chJ.isChecked()==true){
                j="Si";
            }
            else{
                j="No";
            }
            if(chC.isChecked()==true){
                c="Si";
            }
            else{
                c="No";
            }
            if(chMo.isChecked()==true){
                mo="Si";
            }
            else{
                mo="No";
            }
            try{
                HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost("http://proyectoabel.tk/android/disponibilidad.php?usuario="+usuario+"&v="+v+"&sm="+sm+"&st="+st+"&dm="+dm+"&dt="+dt+"&l="+l+"&m="+m+"&x="+x+"&j="+j+"&c="+c+"&mo="+mo);
                httpclient.execute(httppost);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Disponibilidad modificada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("Conexion: ",e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Conexión fallida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });
}
}
```

And this the code of the PHP script

```
include"../conexion.php";
$usu=$_GET['usuario'];
list($apellido, $licencia)=explode(' ', $usu);
$v=$_GET['v'];
$sm=$_GET['sm'];
$st=$_GET['st'];
$dm=$_GET['dm'];
$dt=$_GET['dt'];
$l=$_GET['l'];
$m=$_GET['m'];
$x=$_GET['x'];
$j=$_GET['j'];
$c=$_GET['c'];
$mo=$GET['mo'];
$mysqli=new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $clave, $basedatos);
$mysqli->set_charset("latin1");
if($mysqli->connect_error){
    echo "Error n".$mysqli->connect_error;
}
if($result1=$mysqli->query("SELECT Codigo_arbitro FROM EQUIPO_ARBITRAL WHERE Apellidos LIKE '%$apellido%' AND Licencia='$licencia'")){
    while($row=$result1->fetch_array()){    
        $codigo=$row["Codigo_arbitro"];
    }
}
else{
    echo $mysqli->error;
}
if($result=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM DISPONIBILIDAD WHERE Codigo_arbitro=$codigo")){
    if($result->num_rows==0){
        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO DISPONIBILIDAD VALUES ($codigo, '$v', '$sm', '$st', '$dm', '$dt', '$l', '$m', '$x', '$j', '$c', '$mo')");
    }
    else{
        $mysqli->query("UPDATE DISPONIBILIDAD SET V='$v', SM='$sm', ST='$st', DM='$dm', DT='$dt', L='$l', M='$m', X='$x', J='$j', Coche='$c', Moto='$mo' WHERE Codigo_arbitro=$codigo");
    }
}
else{
    echo $mysqli->error;
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Comment: sure you do - lots of single quotes, double quotes, dollar signs....IF anything is out of place, SQLite will complain.  I suggest you make a local string variable and verify the string is correctly formed before  doing your query.

Comment: I solve the problem with the url encoding. Now the problem is  in the next line when I execute the httppost. This is the error: `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`